# Why slashes Are put in routerLink Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

Why **leading slashes** are put in **routerLink** like,

```
<a [routerLink]="['/home']" [routerLinkActive]="['active']">Home</a>
```

This `<a [routerLink]="['home']" [routerLinkActive]="['active']">Home</a>` code without slashes also works fine for me,and also inside `'forRoot'` method there are no leading slashes in `path: "home"` (no leading slashes here)

```
 RouterModule.forRoot([
    {path:'home',component:HomeComponent},
    {path:'**',component:PageNotFoundComponent}
    ])
```

And in some sites i saw  trailing slashes also

```
const routes: Routes = [    
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home/.', pathMatch: 'full'},    
  { path: 'home/.', component: HomeComponent },          
];
```

(notice trailing slashes in path attribute above and also dot   '.' after trailing slash)
with router link

```
<a [routerLink]="['/home/.']" [routerLinkActive]="['active']">Home</a>
```

(router link also has **trailing** and **leading** slashes)
I am confused,please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.) The leading slash means the route shall start from the **root** of the routes array. So for example, the structure of your routes is like this

```
 RouterModule.forRoot([
{path:'home',component:HomeComponent},
{path:'admin', component: AdminComponent, children:[
    {path:'home', component: AdminHomeComponent},
    {path:'users', component:AdminUsersComponent}
]}
{path:'**',component:PageNotFoundComponent}
])
```

Here there are two routes with path **home**, one on the route of the array that that has **HomeComponent** and one inside the **admin** that has **AdminHomeComponent.** Now suppose if you were in the **admin/users** path and in the **AdminUsersComponent** you had a route like this

```
<a [routerLink]="['home']">Application Home</a>
```

It would redirect to **home** path that has **AdminHomeComponent** because without the leading slash the paths would be **relative to the current route** of the router. If from the nested path, you want to go to the root **home** component you would use leading slash like this

```
<a [routerLink]="['/home']">Application Home</a>
```

2.) A trailing slash (backslash at the end of the url) is placed in a url for the SEO purpose. To explain this, lets say you have a route array like this

```
const routes: Routes = [  
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'},  
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },  
  { path: 'about', component: AboutUsComponent },  
  { path: 'contactus', component: ContactUsComponent }  
];
```

And if you navigate to a page with **http://localhost:4200/about** or with **http://localhost:4200/about/** you will be shown same **AboutUsComponent**. For us they both would mean same urls but for search engines they would mean different urls. And having two different urls rendering same content, is not a good SEO practice. Thats why developers put trailing slash in the url and devise a mechanism to add a trailing slash itself in the route if its missing by default (or give a permanent redirect 301 so that not to confuse search engines)

Here is a [nice link](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/angular-7-routing-with-preserving-trailing-slash-in-url/) that explains trailing slash in angular routes.

Comment: Problem with the Solution provided by your link is that the source code does have href and Canonical with the /. at the end what is also not good for search engines.